# iSniff-GPS: Certificate Verification

Tags: tls, http, ios, python, geolocation

## iSniff-GPS

I came across an interesting sounding project on **GitHub**, called **iSniff-GPS.**
I decided to check it out, but i experienced some issues when trying to use the web interface.

---

### Instructions

Taken from: ***https://github.com/hubert3/iSniff-GPS***.

> To use the web interface:
>
> 1. Install or update required Python modules by running `pip install -U -r requirements.txt`.
> 2. Initialise an empty database by running `./manage.py syncdb`.
> 3. Start the web interface by running `./manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`.

---

### ./manage.py

Here is the contents of `manage.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "iSniff_GPS.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

---

### Error

When accessing the web server; I get a map of Melbourne, VICTORIA. (Australia).
 Similar to the following image:

[image: Map]

Any attempts to further navigate this interface are fruitless and provokes an errors.
Similar to the following message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:791: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
```

---

### Using Certifi with urllib3

So I follow the instructions at: ***https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html***.
Until I get to: ***https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#certifi-with-urllib3***.

> Setup your pool to require a certificate and provide the certifi bundle:

```
import urllib3
import certifi

http = urllib3.PoolManager(
    cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', # Force certificate check.
    ca_certs=certifi.where(),  # Path to the Certifi bundle.
)

# You're ready to make verified HTTPS requests.
try:
    r = http.request('GET', 'https://example.com/')
except urllib3.exceptions.SSLError as e:
    # Handle incorrect certificate error.
    ...
```

- What am I supposed to do with this block of code?
- Does it require modification in order to work properly?
- Does it belong inside `manage.py`/`connectionpool.py`?

---

### Additional Information

My experience with Python is minimal but I've tried a bunch of different things over the last few days, trying to get this to work. Here are a few screenshots, depicting some of the various error messages; generated in the background, while i was trying to play with the web interface:

[image: MyTerm]
[image: MyTermAgain]
[image: MyTermAgainAgain]